# How to wire up a mini potentiometer?

Tags: resistance, potentiometer, lm317

Sorry for the crappy schematic, but how do I wire up a potentiometer to have variabile resistance (like the symbol an the bottom). I'm using it in a 317T voltage regulator circut.

[image: kek]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See pic below.  As shown, resistance will increase with clockwise movement of the shaft.  To increase resistance with CCW movement, place the jumper between the center (wiper) and the left terminal.

While this isn't a mini pot, it demonstrates the use of the three terminals.  Mainly just need to establish which one is the wiper on the pot you're using.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use the two terminals you have marked as "R = 0 to 8k".  There are two ways to do this, one connection should always be the wiper, and your selection of which other to use can be based on whether you want resistance to increase or decrease by turning the adjustment a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

The wiper is the terminal that should  always be connected, either in the ground or the supply voltage.  when the potentiometer is used as a variable resistor, only 02 terminals(with a wiper ) are connected.
this article can help you:
https://sciencing.com/how-to-wire-a-variable-resistor-12176736.html